# Image fadeIn not working with Internet Explorer or Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a basic sequence that fades in images. There are three images total and they `fadeIn`. I have this same method throughout this same page and it works, so I am confused why it will not work in Internet Explorer and Firefox.

This is my code:

```js
//Home Img delay/fadein
$(function() {
  var oTop = $('#home-img-block-section').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
    console.log(pTop + ' - ' + oTop);
    if (pTop > oTop) {
      imgDelays();
    }
  });
});


// For three image block resizing

$('.home-img-block img').addClass(function() {
  return (this.width / this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
});

function imgDelays() {
  $('.fadeBlock1').delay(300).fadeIn(500);
  $('.fadeBlock2').delay(600).fadeIn(500);
  $('.fadeBlock3').delay(900).fadeIn(500);
};
```

```css
.home-img-block {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-img-block fadeBlock1"></div>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/caatkq57/)

Why would this not display within the browsers mentioned?

Comment: Works perfectly fine in FF and IE11. Can we see your actual code as a demo? Maybe there is something else wrong with what you are doing.

Comment: @Harry Here you are: https://jsfiddle.net/caatkq57/ . It works in there, just not in FF and IE.

Comment: That fiddle works fine in latest FF (v45) and IE 11 @Becky. I just changed the image URLs as your image is not accessible for me. You do realize that you have to scroll for it to appear right?

Comment: Yes. Mine does not do anything. It works with Chrome just fine. optimumwebdesigns.com ... scroll past the main blue part. You will see it does nothing.

Comment: Can you try `$(document).scrollTop()` or `$(window).scrollTop()` instead of `$('body').scrollTop()` and let me know if it works. `$('body').scrollTop()` always returns 0 in FF and that's why it is not working.

Comment: @Harry As always, you are always right. That was it. I had this issue a while ago, I wish I would have thought of it. Thanks! Create an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be within the scroll handler where `$('body').scrollTop()` is used. It seems to be returning a value of 0 always in Firefox and IE whereas in Chrome it returns the correct value. Due to this, the `pTop` is never greater than the `oTop` and hence the `if` is always falsy and so the function does not get called at all.

Try changing it to `$(document).scrollTop` or `$(window).scrollTop` as both seems to return a value in Firefox, Chrome and IE.

```
$(function() {
  var oTop = $('#home-img-block-section').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    var pTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(pTop + ' - ' + oTop);
    if (pTop > oTop) {
      imgDelays();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers have the same `CSS` settings, and you found a common problem, `inline-block` doesnt work in FF so you need to add the moz specific version of it:

```
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
```

*note it should be above the 'normal' `inline-block`

For IE the workaround as far as I know is:

```
display: inline-block;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
```

Here is an excellent blog post form mozilla about this: [Blog Post](https://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/)

Comment: I'm displaying none, though. Wouldn't the `fadeIn` automatically put it into a block setting?

Comment: Fade in doesnt change the default function of a tag, this is a pain and sucks I know. Check it the blog post.... Cross browser styling is the issue here

Comment: I don't have `display: inline-block` anywhere. I have `display: none;`. That is why I am confused on your answer.

Comment: `inline-block` works with FF and IE (since v7/8). There is absolutely no need for `-moz-inline-stack` anymore. You are referring to a blog post from 2009.